# Is there a way to connect a contact's category to their roles?

Tags: netsuite

I am setting up a company for lead nurturing and marketing automation and I'm in the process of scrubbing up all of the contacts, customers, and leads. The way that we are using NetSuite right now, we don't have any need for a separate contact category and role.

So I want to set up a script to connect the category and role fields, or have the role field always copy what's in the category field.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The "Contact Category" and "Contact Role" fields in NetSuite are two different **CRM list fields**. Which means that:

- In order to create a new "Contact Category", navigate to: Setup -->
  Sales --> CRM Lists --> New --> Contact Category
- And In order to create a new "Contact Role", navigate to: Setup -->
  Sales --> CRM Lists --> New --> Contact Role

And because they are two different list fields, you need to have a 1 to 1 link of both these list values before populating it in your entity record.

One efficient way to do it would be by using a custom record as a reference. Please follow the below procedure to achieve the same:

1. Create a "Custom Record" titled "Contact Category & Roles" [or any appropriate name] with two fields in it: Contact Category (list/record of contact category) and Contact Role (list/record of contact role)
2. Now create each of these "Contact Category & Roles" custom record. For every record, select the Contact Category and the corresponding Contact Role.
3. Hence, in this way you will now have a list of this custom record that gives the Contact Category and its corresponding Contact Role.
4. This custom record can now be used as a reference in scripts.
5. For new records that are created, have a client script deployed. And in the "fieldChanged()" event of the script, write the logic to populate the role field based on what the category field is selected. [So here, when the category field is selected, reference the custom record and see if the category field has a corresponding role value and set it accordingly]
6. And since you are doing a scrub of already existing records, you can achieve the same by writing the above logic (point 5) in a schedule or map/reduce script (i.e by loading each record, getting the category value, referencing the custom record and getting the corresponding role and setting the role value).

**Additional Note:** If the Category values need to be cleaned up, a csv import could be done to achieve the same. You can then run the schedule script to set the role values.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Is there a particular reason I need to create a custom field and I can't just create a script to copy what's in the category field over to role if all of the category options are in the role options?

Comment: Nevermind I understand it now. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: I'm trying to create the new Custom field and I cannot find a way to link the two other lists together. Can you expand on that?

Comment: Hi there. Thank you for your kind response. So as mentioned before you need to create a separate custom record/table (Step 1) and not a custom field. And within this custom record, you need to have two fields (one for contact category and other for contact role). So each record (of this custom record type) that you manually create will have a contact category and the corresponding contact role value. Now, you can use this table as a reference to populate your respective fields in the entity record using a script.